# Stripe Integration with classic ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, stripe-payments

i am trying to integrate stripe payment gateway in classic ASP using vb script , i am very new to ASP and vb script and trying to learn how it could be done.

meanwhile i have got a great resource : [Integrate stripe using Classic ASP](http://nilsson.co/post/103085221039)

i am just trying to do the same as explained in the above article.

My Folder Structure :

/stripe

-aspJSON1.17.asp

-index.asp

--My index.asp file--

```html
<!–#include virtual="aspJSON1.17.asp" –>
<%
Function GetStripe(url,typ)

Set xml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

xml.Open typ, url, False

xml.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer sk_test_mykey"

xml.Send

GetStripe = xml.responseText

Set xml = Nothing

End Function

var_stripe_token = Request(stripeToken)   

var_json = GetStripe("https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers?description=LoremIpsum&card=" & var_stripe_token, "POST")

Set oJSON = New aspJSON

oJSON.loadJSON(var_json)

Response.Write "<pre>JSON returned: " & var_json & "</pre>"
Response.Write "<pre>UserId: " & oJSON.data("id") & "</pre>"
%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Stripe Testing</title>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  // This identifies your website in the createToken call below
   Stripe.setPublishableKey('My_publishkey'); 
  // ...
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
   var $form = $(this);

   // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
   $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

   Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

   // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
   return false;
    });
  });
  
  function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    var $form = $('#payment-form');
    $("#stripeToken").val(response.id); 
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
    $form.get(0).submit();

    
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <h3>Stripe Testing</h3>
<form action="" method="POST" id="payment-form">
  <span class="payment-errors"></span>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Card Number</span>
      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>CVC</span>
      <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
      <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>
    </label>
    <span> / </span>
    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>
  </div>
 <input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" id="stripeToken" value="" />
  <button type="submit">Submit Payment</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

--My aspJSON1.17.asp --

```html
<%
'Februari 2014 - Version 1.17 by Gerrit van Kuipers
Class aspJSON
 Public data
 Private p_JSONstring
 private aj_in_string, aj_in_escape, aj_i_tmp, aj_char_tmp, aj_s_tmp, aj_line_tmp, aj_line, aj_lines, aj_currentlevel, aj_currentkey, aj_currentvalue, aj_newlabel, aj_XmlHttp, aj_RegExp, aj_colonfound

 Private Sub Class_Initialize()
  Set data = Collection()

     Set aj_RegExp = new regexp
     aj_RegExp.Pattern = "\s{0,}(\S{1}[\s,\S]*\S{1})\s{0,}"
     aj_RegExp.Global = False
     aj_RegExp.IgnoreCase = True
     aj_RegExp.Multiline = True
 End Sub

 Private Sub Class_Terminate()
  Set data = Nothing
     Set aj_RegExp = Nothing
 End Sub

 Public Sub loadJSON(inputsource)
  inputsource = aj_MultilineTrim(inputsource)
  If Len(inputsource) = 0 Then Err.Raise 1, "loadJSON Error", "No data to load."
  
  select case Left(inputsource, 1)
   case "{", "["
   case else
    Set aj_XmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    aj_XmlHttp.open "GET", inputsource, False
    aj_XmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/json"
    aj_XmlHttp.setRequestHeader "CharSet", "UTF-8"
    aj_XmlHttp.Send
    inputsource = aj_XmlHttp.responseText
    set aj_XmlHttp = Nothing
  end select

  p_JSONstring = CleanUpJSONstring(inputsource)
  aj_lines = Split(p_JSONstring, Chr(13) & Chr(10))

  Dim level(99)
  aj_currentlevel = 1
  Set level(aj_currentlevel) = data
  For Each aj_line In aj_lines
   aj_currentkey = ""
   aj_currentvalue = ""
   If Instr(aj_line, ":") > 0 Then
    aj_in_string = False
    aj_in_escape = False
    aj_colonfound = False
    For aj_i_tmp = 1 To Len(aj_line)
     If aj_in_escape Then
      aj_in_escape = False
     Else
      Select Case Mid(aj_line, aj_i_tmp, 1)
       Case """"
        aj_in_string = Not aj_in_string
       Case ":"
        If Not aj_in_escape And Not aj_in_string Then
         aj_currentkey = Left(aj_line, aj_i_tmp - 1)
         aj_currentvalue = Mid(aj_line, aj_i_tmp + 1)
         aj_colonfound = True
         Exit For
        End If
       Case "\"
        aj_in_escape = True
      End Select
     End If
    Next
    if aj_colonfound then
     aj_currentkey = aj_Strip(aj_JSONDecode(aj_currentkey), """")
     If Not level(aj_currentlevel).exists(aj_currentkey) Then level(aj_currentlevel).Add aj_currentkey, ""
    end if
   End If
   If right(aj_line,1) = "{" Or right(aj_line,1) = "[" Then
    If Len(aj_currentkey) = 0 Then aj_currentkey = level(aj_currentlevel).Count
    Set level(aj_currentlevel).Item(aj_currentkey) = Collection()
    Set level(aj_currentlevel + 1) = level(aj_currentlevel).Item(aj_currentkey)
    aj_currentlevel = aj_currentlevel + 1
    aj_currentkey = ""
   ElseIf right(aj_line,1) = "}" Or right(aj_line,1) = "]" or right(aj_line,2) = "}," Or right(aj_line,2) = "]," Then
    aj_currentlevel = aj_currentlevel - 1
   ElseIf Len(Trim(aj_line)) > 0 Then
    if Len(aj_currentvalue) = 0 Then aj_currentvalue = aj_line
    aj_currentvalue = getJSONValue(aj_currentvalue)

    If Len(aj_currentkey) = 0 Then aj_currentkey = level(aj_currentlevel).Count
    level(aj_currentlevel).Item(aj_currentkey) = aj_currentvalue
   End If
  Next
 End Sub

 Public Function Collection()
  set Collection = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 End Function

 Public Function AddToCollection(dictobj)
  if TypeName(dictobj) <> "Dictionary" then Err.Raise 1, "AddToCollection Error", "Not a collection."
  aj_newlabel = dictobj.Count
  dictobj.Add aj_newlabel, Collection()
  set AddToCollection = dictobj.item(aj_newlabel)
 end function

 Private Function CleanUpJSONstring(aj_originalstring)
  aj_originalstring = Replace(aj_originalstring, Chr(13) & Chr(10), "")
  aj_originalstring = Mid(aj_originalstring, 2, Len(aj_originalstring) - 2)
  aj_in_string = False : aj_in_escape = False : aj_s_tmp = ""
  For aj_i_tmp = 1 To Len(aj_originalstring)
   aj_char_tmp = Mid(aj_originalstring, aj_i_tmp, 1)
   If aj_in_escape Then
    aj_in_escape = False
    aj_s_tmp = aj_s_tmp & aj_char_tmp
   Else
    Select Case aj_char_tmp
     Case "\" : aj_s_tmp = aj_s_tmp & aj_char_tmp : aj_in_escape = True
     Case """" : aj_s_tmp = aj_s_tmp & aj_char_tmp : aj_in_string = Not aj_in_string
     Case "{", "["
      aj_s_tmp = aj_s_tmp & aj_char_tmp & aj_InlineIf(aj_in_string, "", Chr(13) & Chr(10))
     Case "}", "]"
      aj_s_tmp = aj_s_tmp & aj_InlineIf(aj_in_string, "", Chr(13) & Chr(10)) & aj_char_tmp
     Case "," : aj_s_tmp = aj_s_tmp & aj_char_tmp & aj_InlineIf(aj_in_string, "", Chr(13) & Chr(10))
     Case Else : aj_s_tmp = aj_s_tmp & aj_char_tmp
    End Select
   End If
  Next

  CleanUpJSONstring = ""
  aj_s_tmp = split(aj_s_tmp, Chr(13) & Chr(10))
  For Each aj_line_tmp In aj_s_tmp
   aj_line_tmp = replace(replace(aj_line_tmp, chr(10), ""), chr(13), "")
   CleanUpJSONstring = CleanUpJSONstring & aj_Trim(aj_line_tmp) & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
  Next
 End Function

 Private Function getJSONValue(ByVal val)
  val = Trim(val)
  If Left(val,1) = ":"  Then val = Mid(val, 2)
  If Right(val,1) = "," Then val = Left(val, Len(val) - 1)
  val = Trim(val)

  Select Case val
   Case "true"  : getJSONValue = True
   Case "false" : getJSONValue = False
   Case "null" : getJSONValue = Null
   Case Else
    If (Instr(val, """") = 0) Then
     If IsNumeric(val) Then
      getJSONValue = CDbl(val)
     Else
      getJSONValue = val
     End If
    Else
     If Left(val,1) = """" Then val = Mid(val, 2)
     If Right(val,1) = """" Then val = Left(val, Len(val) - 1)
     getJSONValue = aj_JSONDecode(Trim(val))
    End If
  End Select
 End Function

 Private JSONoutput_level
 Public Function JSONoutput()
  dim wrap_dicttype, aj_label
  JSONoutput_level = 1
  wrap_dicttype = "[]"
  For Each aj_label In data
    If Not aj_IsInt(aj_label) Then wrap_dicttype = "{}"
  Next
  JSONoutput = Left(wrap_dicttype, 1) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & GetDict(data) & Right(wrap_dicttype, 1)
 End Function

 Private Function GetDict(objDict)
  dim aj_item, aj_keyvals, aj_label, aj_dicttype
  For Each aj_item In objDict
   Select Case TypeName(objDict.Item(aj_item))
    Case "Dictionary"
     GetDict = GetDict & Space(JSONoutput_level * 4)
     
     aj_dicttype = "[]"
     For Each aj_label In objDict.Item(aj_item).Keys
       If Not aj_IsInt(aj_label) Then aj_dicttype = "{}"
     Next
     If aj_IsInt(aj_item) Then
      GetDict = GetDict & (Left(aj_dicttype,1) & Chr(13) & Chr(10))
     Else
      GetDict = GetDict & ("""" & aj_JSONEncode(aj_item) & """" & ": " & Left(aj_dicttype,1) & Chr(13) & Chr(10))
     End If
     JSONoutput_level = JSONoutput_level + 1
     
     aj_keyvals = objDict.Keys
     GetDict = GetDict & (GetSubDict(objDict.Item(aj_item)) & Space(JSONoutput_level * 4) & Right(aj_dicttype,1) & aj_InlineIf(aj_item = aj_keyvals(objDict.Count - 1),"" , ",") & Chr(13) & Chr(10))
    Case Else
     aj_keyvals =  objDict.Keys
     GetDict = GetDict & (Space(JSONoutput_level * 4) & aj_InlineIf(aj_IsInt(aj_item), "", """" & aj_JSONEncode(aj_item) & """: ") & WriteValue(objDict.Item(aj_item)) & aj_InlineIf(aj_item = aj_keyvals(objDict.Count - 1),"" , ",") & Chr(13) & Chr(10))
   End Select
  Next
 End Function

 Private Function aj_IsInt(val)
  aj_IsInt = (TypeName(val) = "Integer" Or TypeName(val) = "Long")
 End Function

 Private Function GetSubDict(objSubDict)
  GetSubDict = GetDict(objSubDict)
  JSONoutput_level= JSONoutput_level -1
 End Function

 Private Function WriteValue(ByVal val)
  Select Case TypeName(val)
   Case "Double", "Integer", "Long": WriteValue = val
   Case "Null"      : WriteValue = "null"
   Case "Boolean"     : WriteValue = aj_InlineIf(val, "true", "false")
   Case Else      : WriteValue = """" & aj_JSONEncode(val) & """"
  End Select
 End Function

 Private Function aj_JSONEncode(ByVal val)
  val = Replace(val, "\", "\\")
  val = Replace(val, """", "\""")
  'val = Replace(val, "/", "\/")
  val = Replace(val, Chr(8), "\b")
  val = Replace(val, Chr(12), "\f")
  val = Replace(val, Chr(10), "\n")
  val = Replace(val, Chr(13), "\r")
  val = Replace(val, Chr(9), "\t")
  aj_JSONEncode = Trim(val)
 End Function

 Private Function aj_JSONDecode(ByVal val)
  val = Replace(val, "\""", """")
  val = Replace(val, "\\", "\")
  val = Replace(val, "\/", "/")
  val = Replace(val, "\b", Chr(8))
  val = Replace(val, "\f", Chr(12))
  val = Replace(val, "\n", Chr(10))
  val = Replace(val, "\r", Chr(13))
  val = Replace(val, "\t", Chr(9))
  aj_JSONDecode = Trim(val)
 End Function

 Private Function aj_InlineIf(condition, returntrue, returnfalse)
  If condition Then aj_InlineIf = returntrue Else aj_InlineIf = returnfalse
 End Function

 Private Function aj_Strip(ByVal val, stripper)
  If Left(val, 1) = stripper Then val = Mid(val, 2)
  If Right(val, 1) = stripper Then val = Left(val, Len(val) - 1)
  aj_Strip = val
 End Function

 Private Function aj_MultilineTrim(TextData)
  aj_MultilineTrim = aj_RegExp.Replace(TextData, "$1")
 End Function

 private function aj_Trim(val)
  aj_Trim = Trim(val)
  Do While Left(aj_Trim, 1) = Chr(9) : aj_Trim = Mid(aj_Trim, 2) : Loop
  Do While Right(aj_Trim, 1) = Chr(9) : aj_Trim = Left(aj_Trim, Len(aj_Trim) - 1) : Loop
  aj_Trim = Trim(aj_Trim)
 end function
End Class
%>
```

the problem is that when i run the code it gives the following error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01fa'
>
> Class not defined: 'aspJSON'
>
> /stripe/index.asp, line 24

Please let me know what wrong am i doing.thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're gonna hate me for this. :)

Include files need to be in html comment tags, which have **two** hyphens before/after the angle brackets, not one hyphen like you have.

```
<!-- #include virtual="/path/to/aspJSON1.17.asp" -->
```

```
<!-- #include file="aspJSON1.17.asp" -->
```

Comment: yea you were right , the include statement were required to be in the html comment format , but still virtual attribute dint worked, it said could not find aspJSON1.17.asp. so i had to use file instead.

Comment: @DhirajKarkera: oops, you're right. With the `virtual` syntax, you always have to specify the path to the page you're including, even if it's in the same folder. So you need either `virtual="/path/to/aspJSON1.17.asp"`, or `file="aspJSON1.17.asp"`. I'll edit my answer.