# Stripe REST API in 100% VBScript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, stripe-payments

Is it possible to use the Stripe API in a 100% VBScript scenario with no browser-based token generation?

Cards are not charged in realtime, or even necessarily entered from a web browser, so there's no way to use any of the Javascript or web-based implementations. Orders orders come from call centers where the card information is collected over the phone and stored in a database.

Right now we're using Authorize.Net. A VBScript connects to the database to fetch the card and customer data, posts to the Authorize.Net API, and writes the response/transaction ID back to the database.

Can Stripe replace Authorize.Net in this scenario?

(Please, no comments on PCI compliance and data storage, we're a public company and store card numbers. My question is only about whether this scenario is possible with Stripe's API, if so, where to begin)

Comment: I don't see why not. You'd be able to access COM objects like `WinHttp` to make `https` requests or even just use VBScript to automate `curl` commands to their REST API.

Comment: The Stripe REST API uses a very simple authentication method, there is no digital signatures to deal with just a basic secret API key you send in the header of the request which you can do using the `WinHttp` object as @Bond has already mentioned. All responses are JSON so you will need to use something like [ASPJSON](http://www.aspjson.com/) to parse the JSON into workable object structures that you can use and manipulate in Classic ASP.

Comment: [This existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31096266/692942) links to [a tutorial](http://nilsson.co/post/103085221039) which looks as though it may help you, but bear in mind that some formatting issues exist with the post. For example `<!-#include ...->` is incorrect and should be `<!--#include ...-->`.

Comment: The open question linked uses stripe.js (and so does all of the sample code I've come across); I'm trying to figure out how to do this using pure REST without any client side code. I already have the cards and customer data in a database.

I guess it's more lack of familiarity with their API than anything else. I just need to charge cards, don't need their other features like customer objects or saving tokens. Hiring a classic ASP developer seems to be a bit of a challenge these days. :P

Comment: @RonRule The linked question might use the `stripe.js` but the [linked tutorial](http://nilsson.co/post/103085221039) I mentioned is pure server-side Classic ASP that uses `WinHttp` to talk to stripe.